# Mysql: Count rows for period of time

Tags: mysql

I have a table videos and I need to create top videos for it.

For the start i was using simple counter per video row and updated it on each user view like that:

```
UPDATE videos SET video_id=video_id+1 WHERE video_id=?
```

After that we have decided to create three different tops and add some unification to the results per ip, to make tops more accurate:
- top of the day
- top of the week
- top of the month

I have added new table to count each user view as a separate row.

```
INSERT INTO video_views(video_id,date,ip) VALUES(video_id,current date,user ip)
```

Everything went ok until video_views table became very big.

Here is query for top:

```
SELECT COUNT(vv.`view_id`) as counter,v.* FROM video v
LEFT JOIN video_views vv ON vv.`video_id`=v.`video_id`
WHERE vv.`date`>1320120130 /* It's the time = current time minus week or day */
GROUP BY v.`video_id`
ORDER BY counter DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Problem starts at this part:

```
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Query takes about 20 seconds to finish. Without order it's as usually 16-32ms. Here is what EXPLAIN telling:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,vv,range,date,video_id,date,5,NULL,149552,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,SIMPLE,v,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,movieslv_website.vv.video_id,1,
```

As i understand it's because of "Using temporary" , mysql creates temporary table to fit the results and sort them afterwards?

What solutions can be applied to help in this situation?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the left join with an inner join and also try not selecting all fields v.*, just the needed ones. Also take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html).

> The maximum size for in-memory temporary tables is the minimum of the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size values

Maybe increasing the in-memory temporary tables will increase speed too.